# How to clear list files before listing another one?

Tags: javascript

```
   function listFiles() {
var x = document.getElementById("ResultShown").value;

var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 180);
var n = date.toISOString().split('.')[0] ;
  var test = false;

    gapi.client.drive.files.list({

      pageSize: x,
     q: "starred = "+test+" and viewedByMeTime < '"+n+"'",
     orderBy: 'quotaBytesUsed desc',

      fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name, viewedByMeTime, mimeType,     quotaBytesUsed, webViewLink)",

     }

    ).then(function(response) {
    var table = document.getElementById('content');
      appendPre('Files:');
            appendRow(table, ['Name', 'Last Viewed', 'Link', 'Size'], 'th');
      var files = response.result.files;

    var table = document.getElementById('content');

      if (files && files.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          var file = files[i];



           appendRow(table, [
   file.name +" ",
  file.viewedByMeTime.split('.')[0]+" ",
   link(file.webViewLink),
   file.quotaBytesUsed + ' bytes'
 ])

        }
      } else {
        appendPre('No files found.');
      }
    });
  }
```

Currently, every time I click a button to activate this function, a new list comes up, what can I add to it that will make the button clear the old list before putting a new one out?

**Edit #1:** 
In this screenshot, you can see that every time I press a button to call on list file function, a new list comes up, instead of having a million list, I want it so everytime I clear the button, it clears the old list and replaces it with a new list

[image]

I only want one thing showing at a time.

Comment: "every time I click...a new list comes up..what can I add...putting a new one out?"

Comment: does appendPre do?

Comment: @inspired from what I've tested, it works like document.write

Comment: i'm not clear on what you want to do here

Comment: One sec, let me grab you a screenshot.

Comment: @inspired, Ok, I edited the post, thank you for your patience.

Comment: where is this displayed? The "Files: Hello..". I think what your'e asking is you want it to only display one at a time?

Comment: Yup, I want it to only show the recent one that I called and clear the old one

Comment: I can help you with this, but could you update the question to reflect the latest version of the code you are using?

Comment: @gyre Done! Sorry for the inconvenience. Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all but the header row in your table element before adding new rows to it:

```
var table = document.getElementById('content');
var rows = table.rows;
while (rows.length > 1) rows[1].parentNode.removeChild(rows[1]);
```

### Full Updated Code

```js
appendPre('Files:');
appendRow(table, ['Name', 'Last Viewed', 'Link', 'Size'], 'th');

function listFiles() {
  var x = document.getElementById("ResultShown").value;

  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 180);
  var n = date.toISOString().split('.')[0];
  var test = false;

  gapi.client.drive.files.list({

      pageSize: x,
      q: "starred = " + test + " and viewedByMeTime < '" + n + "'",
      orderBy: 'quotaBytesUsed desc',

      fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name, viewedByMeTime, mimeType,     quotaBytesUsed, webViewLink)",

    }

  ).then(function(response) {
    var table = document.getElementById('content');
    var files = response.result.files;

    var table = document.getElementById('content');
    var rows = table.rows;
    while (rows.length > 1) rows[1].parentNode.removeChild(rows[1]);

    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];

        appendRow(table, [
          file.name + " ",
          file.viewedByMeTime.split('.')[0] + " ",
          link(file.webViewLink),
          file.quotaBytesUsed + ' bytes'
        ])

      }
    } else {
      appendPre('No files found.');
    }
  });
}
```

---

**Note:** This answer may seem out of context, because it builds on my answers to [additional questions OP has asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42731469/7256039) concerning the same project.

Comment: Thanks! One issue thou, it spawns a new set of appendPre('Files:'); and
    appendRow(table, ['Name', 'Last Viewed', 'Link', 'Size'], 'th'); how do I get them to not spawn in new set?

Comment: Just move them outside of the function entirely. I have updated the example above; you should see what I mean at the top.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry bout that. Thank you again for everything!