# How do I delete multiple files at once in Drive API for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-apis-explorer

```
function deleteFiles(fileId,supportsTeamDrives) {



var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 180);
var n = date.toISOString().split('.')[0] ;
  var test = false;

  gapi.client.drive.files.list({
    pageSize: x,
     q: "starred = "+test+" and viewedByMeTime < '"+n+"'",
     orderBy: 'quotaBytesUsed desc',

      fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name, viewedByMeTime, mimeType, quotaBytesUsed)",

     }

    )

  .then(function(response) {
  var files = response.result.files;

      if (files && files.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          var file = files[i];
          var file_id = file.id,
          )');

           }}

  var request = gapi.client.drive.files.delete({
  supportsTeamDrives: 'false',
 fileId: file_id ,
  });   }

 request.execute(function(resp) { });




}
```

I want this function to list out the fileIDs, as as each fileID is put out, they get deleted. How do I combine list file and delete file functions together for this to work?

Currently I separated them into two functions, but the variable fileID only saves the last fileID outputted, thus, the delete function would only delete one file, the last file listed. I want it to list and output every file to a varable and as its listed it gets deleted. What can I change or add in my goal to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you need to do something after all of the deletes are finished? right now my answer only executes the delete Promises, but doesn't provide away for you to know when its complete or catch errors.

Comment: @inspired, thanks for the answer! So what I want is to have a update at the end when everything is deleted, but I also want the list (provided by  the list file function that I have) to be updated as each file is deleted. However, from my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712122/how-to-clear-list-files-before-listing-another-one, I have issues with clearing the board before another list of files is deleted. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter your code to delete the file in your loop:

```
    function deleteFiles(fileId, supportsTeamDrives) {

    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 180);
    var n = date.toISOString().split('.')[0];
    var test = false;

    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                pageSize: x,
                q: "starred = " + test + " and viewedByMeTime < '" + n + "'",
                orderBy: 'quotaBytesUsed desc',

                fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name, viewedByMeTime, mimeType, quotaBytesUsed)",

            }

        )

        .then(function(response) {
            var files = response.result.files;

            if (files && files.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    var file = files[i];
                    var file_id = file.id;
                    deleteFile(file_id);
                }
            }

        });
}

// method used to delete the files
function deleteFile(file_id) {
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.delete({
        supportsTeamDrives: 'false',
        fileId: file_id,
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {});
}
```

Comment: What can I implement to it so it alerts the user that its finished when its done?

Comment: Are you not calling Delete  API again and again for deleting each file.? Is it not inefficient?