# How do I set up `appendLink` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Modeling after:

```
function appendPre(message) {
    var pre = document.getElementById('content');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
    pre.appendChild(textContent);
}

appendPre('Files:');
```

How do I make an `appendLink` function that allows me to use `appendLink('link')` to print out a link?

This is what I have so far:

```
function appendLink(url) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  var textContent = document.createTextNode(url + '\n');
  link.appendChild(textContent);
  link.href = 'test.com';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function to generate a link (anchor element) from a given `url` and `text`:

```
function link (url, text) {
  var a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = url
  a.textContent = text || url
  return a
}
```

Here is how you can integrate it into your table (building on my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42730819/how-do-i-get-appendpre-into-a-table)):

```js
function link (url, text) {
  var a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = url
  a.textContent = text || url
  return a
}

function appendRow (table, elements, tag) {
  var row = document.createElement('tr')
  elements.forEach(function(e) {
    var cell = document.createElement(tag || 'td')
    if (typeof e === 'string') {
      cell.textContent = e
    } else {
      cell.appendChild(e)
    }

    row.appendChild(cell)
  })
  table.appendChild(row)
}


var file = {
  name: 'hello',
  viewedByMeTime: '2017-03-11T01:40:31.000Z',
  webViewLink: 'http://drive.google.com/134ksdf014kldsfi0234lkjdsf0314/',
  quotaBytesUsed: 0
}


var table = document.getElementById('content')

// Create header row
appendRow(table, ['Name', 'Date', 'Link', 'Size'], 'th')

// Create data row
appendRow(table, [
  file.name,
  file.viewedByMeTime.split('.')[0],
  link(file.webViewLink), // Note the enclosing call to `link`
  file.quotaBytesUsed + ' bytes'
])
```

```css
#content td,
#content th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#content {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table id="content">
</table>
```

Comment: I tested this and this is all I got: NameDateLinkSize. They are now jammed together and everything else won't show. However, if I change link(file.webViewLink), back to just file.webViewLink, everything back to normal, except without the link.

Comment: Could you post your failing code as a JSFiddle for me to view and debug? That would be the easiest way for me to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/y4x7c73d/. Not everything is working in the result box for some reason thou. :(

Comment: Well, your JSFiddle doesn't appear to include all of the necessary scripts, because I keep getting errors like `gapi.client is undefined` and `gapi.client.drive is undefined`, etc. Also, you should only have ONE element with an id of `content`, so remove `<pre id="content">` and maybe that will do the trick.

Comment: I removed it <pre id="content">, the text aren't so clumped together but still nothing shows up. I updated it and put everything in the html file so you can just copy and paste that. Also I am running it in http://localhost:8000 like what the DriveAPI guide: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js told me to do. Hope that you can help me solve my issue.

Comment: If you open up the web console, what errors are displayed? And also, could you send me a link to the updated version of your JSFiddle (the old one didn't change)

Comment: Alright sorry, heres the new link: https://jsfiddle.net/y4x7c73d/3/. Opening console, it says that link is not a function for some reason.

Comment: Lol, you have a variable named `link` in your scope already. You need to rename one or the other. Remove `var link = document.getElementById('link');` on line 152 of your JS code.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe that was the issue! Also, one last thing, and I am sorry for being so needy, but can you help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712122/how-to-clear-list-files-before-listing-another-one

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a different parameter for the link's text:

```js
function appendLink(target, url, text) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  var textContent = document.createTextNode(text);
  link.appendChild(textContent);
  link.href = url;
  target.appendChild(link);
}
var link = document.getElementById('link');
appendLink(link, '//stackoverflow.com', 'Link to Stackoverflow');
```

```html
<div id="link"></div>
```

Comment: Can I print it out without the <div id="link"></div>? I want it to directly follow appendPre. It doesn't seem to show without the div.

Comment: Without div, nothing is displayed, I want appendLink to print something out like appendPre except with a hyperlink.