# How do I get `appendPre` into a table?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using DriveAPI to list a bunch of files with their names, last modified date, etc.

This is the `appendPre` function:

```
 function appendPre(message) {
    var pre = document.getElementById('content');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
    pre.appendChild(textContent);
  }
```

and this is the code the writes it out:

```
 appendPre(file.name + ' (' + file.viewedByMeTime.split('.')[0] + ')'+ ' (' + file.webViewLink + ')' +' (' + file.quotaBytesUsed + ' bytes)');
```

How do I organize this into a table where one column represents the name, another the time, etc. I want it to look a bit like this:
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to make an actual HTML table? You cannot embed one in a `<pre>` element, so you need to post your HTML structure so we can explain how to modify it.

Comment: @gyre yes I am trying to fit it into a html structure table, but unfortunately, I have almost nothing in my html code.

Comment: I am not sure how I can put the data in a html table :(

Comment: Give me a minute to formulate an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot embed a `<table>` into a `<pre>` element, so you need to change your HTML structure a little bit. The rest is just creating and inserting DOM nodes like `tr`, `td`, and `th` from your JS code.

### Example Implementation

```js
function appendRow (table, elements, tag) {
  var row = document.createElement('tr')
  elements.forEach(function (e) {
    var cell = document.createElement(tag || 'td')
    if (typeof e === 'string') {
      cell.textContent = e
    } else {
      cell.appendChild(e)
    }
    
    row.appendChild(cell)
  })
  table.appendChild(row)
}


var file = {
  name: 'hello', 
  viewedByMeTime: '2017-03-11T01:40:31.000Z',
  webViewLink: 'http://drive.google.com/134ksdf014kldsfi0234lkjdsf0314/',
  quotaBytesUsed: 0
}


var table = document.getElementById('content')

// Create header row
appendRow(table, ['Name', 'Date', 'Link', 'Size'], 'th')

// Create data row
appendRow(table, [
  file.name,
  file.viewedByMeTime.split('.')[0],
  file.webViewLink,
  file.quotaBytesUsed + ' bytes'
])
```

```css
#content td, #content th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#content {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table id="content">
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will tell you if I need more help :)

Comment: Alright it worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Can you also check out my post here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42730172/how-do-i-set-up-appendlink-in-javascript/42730208#42730208 and how I can do appendLink without using div?

Comment: I just answered your other question (and had to change the code in this thread a little, too). Let me know whether it solves your problem.